# What does path-connected property correspond to in Gelfand duality?

Tags: general-topology, operator-algebras

A commutative C* algebra $A$ correspond to algebra of continuous function from locally compact Hausdorff space, where that space is the spectrum of $A$. Many properties of the space can be obtained from properties of $A$. I am wondering if spectrum of $A$ is path connected, what property of $A$ should have?

Comment: Vector spaces (in particular, C*-algebras) are always path conneted: if $v,w$ are vectors, then $tv + (1-t)w$ is a path from w to v. Do you mean if the spectrum of $A$ is path connected?

Comment: Yes,I have edited the question

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but here is an interesting related post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82871/reference-request-for-translating-from-top-to-c-alg?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but the following paper, Section 5, deals with a slightly weaker property, approximate path connectedness:

> *Hadwin, Don; Shulman,
> Tatiana*, [**Tracial stability for
> $C^*$-algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00020-018-2430-1),
> Integral Equations Oper. Theory 90, No. 1, Paper No. 1, 35 p. (2018).
> [ZBL1396.46045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1396.46045).